# R: Saving svalue of gdroplist to a vector

Tags: r, vector, gwidgets

I am trying to concatenate multiple options from a gdroplist to a vector. When I run this code on console, it works fine. But it won't work when I want it to work on a button press.

```
leftlist<-vector()
left<-gdroplist(itemsnames,container = g2_mba)
addleft<-function(h,...){
   s<-svalue(left)
   c(leftlist,s, recursive=TRUE)
}
b5<-gbutton(text=" Add to left", container = g2_mba, handler = addleft)
```

I have also tried `append` method for a vector but the vector won't update on the button click. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen in `addleft`? Right now it returns a value but you don't assign that anywhere so nothing is updated or changed.

Comment: I expect the `svalue` to be added to the vector `leftist`.

Comment: You can *assign* in a handler, but you need to a) assign it and b) do so in a binding outside of the scope of the handler. Something like `leftlist <<- c(leftlist, s)` should work.

Comment: Thank you. The `<<-` operator did the trick. I had tried it before but it was just `leftist<<-svalue(left)` and that didn't work.